# Group SQL data by JSON arrays

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, highcharts

I am working on a page for teachers that shows results of students' performance on a test.

To display a graph I want to use `Highcharts`  JavaScript library.

So far I have a `PHP` script using `PDO` to create JSON data that later can be fed to `Highcharts` from a different page.

**My problem:**
How do I group all data from the same `student` in an array? See the last example for what I wish to achieve. Also: I wish to enclose all data in an overarching JSON array.

**I want this:**

```
[{
  "student": "Andreas",
  "level" : [4, 3]
}, {
  "student": "Eivind",
  "level" : [4, 5]
}, {
  "student": "Ole",
  "level" : [4, 3]
}]
```

**This is what my PHP looks like:**

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

$school = $_GET["school"];
$class = $_GET["class"];

//initial query
$query = 'SELECT student, taskid, level FROM task
            WHERE school=' . '"' . $school . '"' .  ' AND class=' . '"' . $class . '" ORDER BY student';

//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($rows) {
    $response["posts"]   = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post               = array();
        $post["student"]       = $row["student"];
        $post["level"]         = $row["level"];


        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);


} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```

**This is what I get from the PHP:**

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "student": "Andreas",
      "level": 4
    },
    {
      "student": "Andreas",
      "level": 3
    },
    {
      "student": "Eivind",
      "level": 4
    },
    {
      "student": "Eivind",
      "level": 5
    },
    {
      "student": "Ole",
      "level": 4
    },
    {
      "student": "Ole",
      "level": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an array like this pretty easily by using the student names as array keys. After you have built the array, you can use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to convert the string keys back to numeric keys.

```
...
if ($rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $posts[$row['student']]['student'] = $row['student'];
        $posts[$row['student']]['level'][] = $row['level'];
    }
    $response = array_values($posts);

    echo json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

} else { ...
```

This should give you the following `$response`:

```
[
  {
    "student": "Andreas",
    "level": [4, 3]
  },
  {
    "student": "Eivind",
    "level": [4, 5]
  },
  {
    "student": "Ole",
    "level": [4, 3]
  }
]
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data=[ 
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },
 { "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },
 { "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } 
];

var res = alasql('SELECT category, sum(hits) AS hits, sum(bytes) as bytes \
FROM ? \
GROUP BY category \
ORDER BY bytes DESC',[data]);
```

You will get output as:

```
[{"category":"Search Engines","hits":13,"bytes":673684},
 {"category":"Content Server","hits":3,"bytes":88930},
 {"category":"Internet Services","hits":1,"bytes":3690},
 {"category":"Business","hits":1,"bytes":2847}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In php you can do this:

In your foreach

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $post               = array();
    $post["student"]       = $row["student"];
    $post["level"]         = $row["level"];


    //update our repsonse JSON data
    array_push($response["posts"], $post);
}
```

you need to do something like this:

```
<?php
$response = array();
$response["posts"]   = array();

$students = array("student1", "student2", "student3", "student1");

$tempArray = array();

foreach ($students as $student) {
    $lvl        = 1;
    if(!isset($tempArray[$student])){
              $tempArray[$student] =  array("name" => $student, "level" => array($lvl));
    }
    else{
        $tempArray[$student]["level"][] = $lvl;
    }
}
    // add it to the array
   $response["posts"] = $tempArray;

   // encode array
   $response = json_encode($response);

   echo "<br><br><br> ";

// example

// decode and make it a array for easier looping.
$response = (array)json_decode($response);
$responsePosts = (array) $response["posts"];

// foreach post
foreach($response["posts"] as $keyP => $valueP){

        // convert to array same as above
        $valueP = (array) $valueP;


        // key that is kinda useless but made it the student name so i can easily see if it already exists
        echo "key :".$keyP." <br />";

        // name of the student
        echo "name :".$valueP["name"]." <br />";

        // all the levels
        echo "levels: ";
        foreach($valueP["level"] as $lvl){
            echo $lvl." ";
        }

        echo "<br /><br />";
}


?>
```

This should work. Atm i use the student name as a key to see if it already exists otherwise you need to loop through all the arrays and do a "name" === $student most likely.

No push is required.

Comment: Thanks! I added ``array_push($response["posts"], $tempArray);`` at the end of the ``foreach`` and this is what I get: http://pastebin.com/n2spXp8H Close, but not there yet.. If I don't do ``array_push`` at the end of ``foreach`` the JSON data returner are null.

Comment: I'll see if i can include the push in my example and make it identical what your asking for. I recommend the answer that @Prashant gave over mine if you can do that.

Comment: This should do it. To get the precise array that you wanted you can do    var_dump($response["posts"][0]); The array push creates a key 0 that i don't know right now how to remove.

Comment: Oke that was a bit dumb of me. I deleted the array_push and just assigned it the array. This should be precisely what you were looking for.

Comment: You lost me on the last couple of edits.. The ´´$students´´ requires to be hardcoded, so then it's of no use when these are generated by actual students. :-( Also, in your latest method I don't get JSON encoded data only some PHP dump.. Thank you for your efforts, but so far edit #2 seems closest.

Comment: I hope my latest edit made more sense to you. I added a example of reading it as well to make it a better example.

The vardump was used to make it more readable in that example. This time around i just made it json.